# Can an SSIS dtsConfig file be secured/encrypted or otherwise protected from viewing?

Tags: security, ssis

I have an SSIS package with a dtsConfig file that contains a user id and password.  The package has a password (EncryptAllWithPassword) which provides some measure of protection when opening in BIDS or creating SQL Agent jobs.

My question is, can the configuration file (package.dtsConfig) itself be secured?    Anyone with access to the deployment folder could view its contents, which doesn't seem very secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct and that's one of my issues with using an XML file for holding secure contents. To protect it, you'd need to use Access Control Lists, [ACL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872(v=vs.85).aspx), and deny rights to everyone but the service account that runs the SSIS package.

In environments where we used file configuration, our deployment strategy would look something like

- \server\SSIS\Packages\Project
- \server\SSIS\Configs

That way developers could see what is current deployed because we'd grant read access to the Packages folder and deny access to the Configs folder.

2012+ with the Project Deployment Model gets this right with their built-in encryption for the SSISDB Environments and the ability to mark entities as Sensitive.